# consuming java web service in C# applications

Tags: c#, apache, web-services, soapui, apache-axis

I am going to develop a C# application using web service but the service is developed by Apache Axis2 and I can not handle the service to integrate adding service reference in C#. I get no response and only format exception.
I don't have service code, it's like ready-to-use web service, just give service reference and get started to use it.

The web service wsdl address is:
https://pttws.ptt.gov.tr/PttBilgi/services/Sorgu?wsdl

I also tried to run the service with SOAP UI but the XML response I get is like below:

```
<faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /PttBilgi/services/Sorgu.SorguHttpSoap11Endpoint/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>
```

The raw response is like below, too which is but with some technical detail:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 07:20:28 GMT
Server: gizli gizli gizli gizli
X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace: a2_5cc44d1b-0e0c-48a5-a44f-942377e9ab70
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8

<faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /PttBilgi/services/Sorgu.SorguHttpSoap11Endpoint/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>
```

It seems that content type has to be text/html to use it in C# apps but being of the service's content type is application/xml, so it can not convert to read and process the result.

How can I use the service with success, what do I have to do?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

As described in this article at http://wso2.com/library/176/

If Axis2 engine cannot find a service and an operation for a message, it immediately fails, sending a fault to the sender.

If service not found - "Service Not found EPR is "
If service found but not an operation- "Operation Not found EPR is  and WSA Action = "

Comment: The service is found but the operation is not. 
As far as i get, the operation's gotta be a service method. Checked out the resource link but don't have any clue whether there is any chance how to use it in .Net.